# Query to get the sum of subset of colums in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My DB has two tables.

The first table **task_groups** has a unique identifier named `keyid`.

The second table **tasks** holds tasks for different task groups. The table has two columns `advance` and `task_group` (these are the only two relevant to my question).

All tasks in the same task group have the value of `task_group.keyid` in the `task_group` column.

What I want to do is get the sum of all the advance for the tasks in each group.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT SUM(t.advance) 
FROM tasks AS t, task_groups AS tg 
WHERE tg.keyid = t.task_group;
```

However this gets me only 1 result where I should get as many results as there are task groups.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I would also like to UPDATE this into a task group column named avg. I used the group by as instructed, since it worked for a select however the update does not. This is the query I have tried:

```
UPDATE task_groups tg  SET tg.avg = SUM(t.advance) FROM tasks t WHERE (t.task_group = tg.keyid) AND t.task_group != -1 GROUP BY t.task_group
```

Comment: U want another column before sum and a group by, no? Also use explicit join syntax

Comment: Use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query really just needs a `group by`.  But, you should write it with explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT t.task_group, SUM(t.advance)
FROM tasks t JOIN
     task_groups tg 
     ON tg.keyid = t.task_group
GROUP BY t.task_group;
```

But, this version is overkill.  You don't even need the `join`:

```
SELECT t.task_group, SUM(t.advance)
FROM tasks t
GROUP BY t.task_group;
```

Comment: This version worked. I needed it to make an update statement. See task_group has a field where the sum should go: task_group.avg, could you maybe tell me how to write this as an update statement?. I have tried but it does not work (syntax errors)

Comment: @aarelovich . . . You should really ask another question, rather than totally changing the question you have.  Your original question was quite clearly about `select`.

Comment: Yes, I know. Gordon Linoff. Thank you. I have managed to solved it.